# Base64 Image Conversion to PDF and add as an attachment to java mail

Tags: java, pdf, base64, itext, jakarta-mail

I've a base64 code of an image, now the requirement is using base64 create a PDF with an Image in it(using base64 code) and attach it as an email attachment without saving it in any physical location.
This is what i've tried till now i'm getting pdf as attachment, but saying that it is corrupted.

```
<%
String b64Image=request.getParameter("img_val");
b64Image = b64Image.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
b64Image = b64Image.replace(" ", "+");
/*setting all the email properties
.....
.....
*/
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance(decodedBytes);
image.scalePercent(50);
document.add(image);
document.close(); 
/*after this how to add as email attachment iwas not sure so tried with below code*/

/*with the below code im getting attachment, when i open pdf it is saying as corrupted*/                
byte[] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(b64Image.getBytes());
pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(decoded, "application/pdf")));
pdfBodyPart.setFileName("Report.pdf");
pdfBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
multipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);

%>
```

If i'm doing something wrong please let me know. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First try to create the PDF and write it to a file. Is that PDF corrupted? How is the `decodedBytes` value calculated? You know that Base64 images nor PNG are supported in PDF, don't you? iText needs the decoded PNG and will convert it into a compressed bitmap. Also: why don't you create a page that has the same size of the image? Right now, you create an A4 page and you scale the image to 50% of its original size in pixels (where pixels are treated as points), but you have no idea if the image fits the A4 page with the 10 point margins. All of this is very odd.

Comment: This code is odd, you add your image to a pdf (variable `document`) but use `b64Image` after as PDF?? You probably should use `baos`

Comment: creating and writing into that is working fine @BrunoLowagie, when i'm trying to without using any file i'm getting corrupted file. Reg decodedBytes updated the questions, i dont know about compatiability of PNG or Base64, The size of the Image is bigger than landscape, thats why i'm scaling it inside A4. Can you give me few more leads where i can solve this. Thank you :)

Comment: I Tried two ways on how to do that, with image to pdf i was not sure how to add that it as email attachment without saving it, so i tried the 2nd options. I mentioned this in commented part, guide me in any1 of the approach using that i can add pdf as attachment without saving it. Thank you @RC.

Comment: Did you understand what @RC said? You are creating a `baos` which is perfect, but you aren't using the bytes that are stored in `baos`. Instead, you are using `b64Image.getBytes()`. You need to use the bytes stored in `baos` to add the PDF as an attachment instead of adding the image bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it. Thanks a lot for your suggestions :)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
            document.open();
            Image image = Image.getInstance(decodedBytes);
            image.scalePercent(50);
            document.add(image);
            document.close();

            DataSource pdfds = new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
            pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(pdfds));
            //pngBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<dashboard>");
            //pngBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            pdfBodyPart.setFileName("AnnotatedDashboard.pdf");
            multipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart);
```